# Calculate intervals resetting with group change

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate how much time passed since first and last occurrence per group, but minimum date should reset each time group changes over time

```
df <- data.frame(mdate = c(as.Date('2023-01-01'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-01'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-02'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-08'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-09'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-10'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-10'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-11'), 
                           as.Date('2023-01-12'),
                           as.Date('2023-01-13')),
                 group1 = c('A', rep('B',3),rep('A',2), rep('B',4)),
                 group2 = c('C', rep('D',3),rep('E',2), rep('D',4)))
```

I expect the result to look like below

| group1 | group2 | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 1 day |
| B | D | 8 days |
| A | E | 2 days |
| B | D | 4 days |

Comment: When you say "per group", do you mean `group1`, `group2`, or the combination of `group1` and `group2`?

Comment: combination of group1 and group2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table::rleid`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(duration = max(mdate)-min(mdate)+1), .(group1,group2,rleid(group1,group2))][, rleid:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
   group1 group2   duration
   <char> <char> <difftime>
1:      A      C     1 days
2:      B      D     8 days
3:      A      E     2 days
4:      B      D     4 days
```

You could alternatively wrap your use of `data.table::rleid` in a call to `dplyr::reframe()` like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

reframe(
  mutate(df,id=rleid(group1,group2)),
  duration = 1+max(mdate)-min(mdate),
  .by=-mdate
)
```

Output:

```
  group1 group2 id duration
1      A      C  1   1 days
2      B      D  2   8 days
3      A      E  3   2 days
4      B      D  4   4 days
```